# Javassist java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, instrumentation, javassist

I want to instrument a library method to call one of my Class present in javassist agent.

Lets say I have a class:

```
Class A {

    void display() {
        System.out.println("Inside A.dipslay()");
    }
}
```

then when I invoke:

```
method.insertAfter("packageName.A.display()");
```

it throws the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: packageName/A
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(libraryClass)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(libraryClass)
    at com.avekshaa.app.SecurityFilter.sendGet(Class where i call the Library Class)
    at com.avekshaa.app.SecurityFilter.main(Class where i call the Library Class)
```

And when I call it just by name:

```
method.insertAfter("A.display()");
```

then it gives a No such class found Exception.

Comment: I solved the issue by adding the jars path in the manifest file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved the issue by adding the jars path in the javassist manifest file.
Reffer - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29451704/using-javassist-to-log-method-calls-and-argument-values-how-to-make-a-logger-cl)

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Yes . Actually the agent class will be loaded in System class loader and library classes will be loaded in a different location. So we have to make our agents available in the location where other libraries are present.. Once we add our jar path in manifest file it will be available in every location where we will instrument .. Most probably the libraries are loaded in bootstrap classloader which i am not sure about.
You can refer to the above mentioned site for more details.. Its elaborated very properly